# sbteclipse 1.0 not creating eclipse project with scala version 2.11.8 mentioned in build.sbt

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide, sbteclipse

Please find the version used :

SBT version 1.0
Scala IDE 4.7
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.3")

I am trying to create a eclipse project but the project is getting created with scala version  2.12.3 where as my build.sbt mentions scala version 2.11.8. 
As per my understanding project should get created by version mentioned in the build.sbt and the default version in scala ide.

build.sbt mentions the below version

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

Comment: how are you creating the project? can we know the steps you followed?